# fetching field value from array throwing compilation error

Tags: postgresql

While compiling the below code I am getting the following error.

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
```

It is happening because of this code

```
p_csdtl(v_cn).EDT := p_dt;
p_csdtl(v_cn).Amnt := p_totalamt;
p_csdtl(v_cn).STDT := v_curdtl(i).pdtm;
```

Please help me to resolve it.

```
do $$
begin
    create type csd_schema.creRec as(
                                 CS_ID numeric,
                                 STDT DATE,
                                 EDT   DATE,
                                 Amnt numeric);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
END $$;

do $$
begin
    CREATE DOMAIN csd_schema.creinfo as csd_schema.creRec[];
EXCEPTION
    WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
END $$;

 create or replace  function  crm.amtcalc(
                                 p_dt        IN TIMESTAMP(0),
                                 p_pid       IN NUMERIC,
                                 p_csdtl  out csd_schema.creinfo,
                                 p_totalamt out NUMERIC) RETURNS RECORD AS $body$

DECLARE

   v_curdtl crm.curdtl_v; 

    c_curdt cursor is
     select array(select ats.ppdtm, 
            SUM(atr.amount_mny)  
       from amtpays ats, 
            amtdrm atr
      where ats.iq_num = atr.iq_num 
           group by ats.ppdtm);

   v_cn INTEGER := 0;

  begin
     p_totalamt := 0;
     v_cn := 1;

        p_csdtl(v_cn).EDT := p_dt;
        p_csdtl(v_cn).Amnt := p_totalamt;

        OPEN c_curdt;

        FETCH c_curdt INTO v_curdtl; 

        CLOSE c_curdt;

        if (coalesce(array_length(v_curdtl,1),0) > 0) then         
          FOR i IN coalesce(array_lower(v_curdtl,1),0) ..coalesce(array_upper(v_curdtl,1),0)
          LOOP 

            p_csdtl(v_cn).CS_ID := p_pid;
            p_csdtl(v_cn).STDT := v_curdtl(i).pdtm;
            p_csdtl(v_cn).EDT := p_dt;        
            v_cn := v_cn + 1;

           end LOOP;
        end if;    
  end $body$ language plpgsql;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) array elements are accessed with square brackes `p_csdtl[v_cn]`

Comment: That function would better be written as `returns table(...)` (instead of returning an array hidden in an OUT parameter). Then you could also get rid of the additional types that serve no real purpose. You probably can also get rid of the cursor and loop handling, but the actual intent of the function is so obfuscated that it's hard to tell. But if I'm not mistaken, your function simply returns the result of  `select ats.ppdtm, 
       SUM(atr.amount_mny)  
from amtpays ats
  join amtdrm atr on ats.iq_num = atr.iq_num 
group by ats.ppdtm`

Comment: I have removed the code which is working fine. Could you please help me with  "OUT" parameters.